# can't call yum on an Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-ec2, yum

I'm using an Amazon EC2 instance. I fail to call yum both with sudo:

```
$ sudo yum update -y
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/yum: No such file or directory
```

and without sudo:

```
$ yum update -y
-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

It claims to not have a file at `/usr/bin/yum`. However, this file exists:

```
$ [ -f /usr/bin/yum ] && echo "Found" || echo "Not found"
Found
```

Comment: Looks like `/usr/bin/yum` has `#!/usr/bin/python2.7` as a shebang, and `/usr/bin/python2.7` is the missing file.

Comment: You are correct! changing it to "#!/usr/bin/python" has fixed my problem

Comment: The fact that `/usr/bin` does not appear to be in the `PATH` of the `root` user (as suggested by the first error message)  is odd.

Comment: Are you using Amazon Linux, Ubuntu, or something else?